# How to pass the ids of all the checkboxes to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery to enable all the checkboxes in a table with the help of a single check box. Now, I have got a requirement to pass the ids of all the selected checkboxes to a function(selected_checkbox(id)). If I manually check/uncheck a check box present inside a table, Im able to pass that id to the required function. However, when I select the 'chkCheckAll' checkbox to select all the checkboxes present inside the table(which actually uses JQuery), Im unable to pass the ids of all other checkboxes to the javascript function. Pls help

HTML content is available on http://ideone.com/90kiu (I am relatively new to stackoverflow, so I didnt understand on how to put code in this area)

Comment: FYI: You can add inline code by surrounding it with backticks, and you can do code blocks by adding four spaces before each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each creating an array of id's like so:

```
var ids = [];
$("form input:checkbox").each(function() {
    //check the checkbox
    $(this).prop("checked", true);;
    //add the id to the array
    ids.push(this.id);
});
//check all the checkboxes and return an array of id's
var ids = $("form input:checkbox").prop("checked", true).id();
```

Comment: You can change the jQuery selector to `$("form input:checkbox:checked")` and not bother with the `prop` check.

Answer (score 1):

To get all checkboxe ids:

```
var ids= $('input[type="checkbox"]').id();
```

or jquery has a [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
var ids = $('input:checked').id();
```

if you're trying to just get the checked.

Answer (score 0):

$('input:checked').serialize();

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
```

It will return all Checkboxes as an array. You can do further things using them.